# How to allow seamless navigation of a bookdown book with keyboard arrow keys?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Say you are reading an online book that has been published with [`bookdown`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/bookdown/index.html). For example, let's take the manual itself:

[bookdown: Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/)

If you click your pointer in the main content (text) of the window to give it focus, you can navigate page text with the <kbd>arrow up</kbd> or <kbd>arrow down</kbd> keys. In addition, you can navigate to a new page with the <kbd>arrow left</kbd> and <kbd>arrow right</kbd> keys.

However, once you navigate to a new a page, the focus is no longer in the main content (text) of the page. You can still navgiate to a new page with the left/right, but you can not navigate the text with up/down (without a lot of <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift + tab</kbd> gymastics).

Is it possible to make the default focus on new page navigation to the main text? Is this a bookdown setting or something else?

Comment: I guess this question might be more related to web-browsers than R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of **bookdown** and [I just fixed it](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/ff6cd68bdb5216a3a90cf5338749e2c2b39eb214) in the dev version [on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown):

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```